# automator ethernet toggle high sierra

Tags: macos, network, automator, automation, ethernet

I have been trying to create a service for toggling ethernet on off, but can't manage to get it right.

It is for os x high sierra.

So far I have this, it runs with no error and it does appear on my services menu, but it does not toggle the ethernet connection.

I have tried some code for airport and it works. But I really need it for Ethernet 1, en0.

```
on run {input, parameters}

(* do shell script "networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled Ethernet 1 off" user name “xxxx” password “xxxx” with administrator privileges
do shell script "networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled Ethernet 1 on" user name "xxxx" password "xxxx" with administrator privileges *)

return input end run
```

I have done some workflows recording actions for this but it just a bit to slow to run for my needs. If it could run faster, I wouldn’t feel this automation  is a hassle.

Is there a faster or more reliable way to automate this?

Comment: Creepy? What’s creepy about workflow recordings?

Comment: it just keeps asking for privacy settings for letting automator run, it is just to slow for me.    and Creepy as in: SLOW          ... Anyway is there some one with a better input?

Comment: did you try `networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled Ethernet 1 off` in Terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not need administrator privileges (I don't need them in order to toggle Wi-Fi on/off).  But the problem you're having is likely because you didn't put `"Ethernet 1"` in quotes.  So, assuming your ethernet connection is, indeed, called "Ethernet 1", then the command to turn your ethernet off looks like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    do shell script "networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled \"Ethernet 1\" off"

return input end run
```

If you want to toggle it on/off depending on its current state, then you can do this:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    do shell script ¬
        "[[ \"$(networksetup -getnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1')\" = \"Enabled\" ]] \
         && networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1' off \
         || networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1' on"

end run
```

But, since your entire AppleScript is, in fact, a shell command wrapped inside a `do shell script` command, then I'd recommend using an **Execute Shell Script** action in your *Automator* workflow instead of an AppleScript one.  Then you can simply write the command out in its naked form, which is much more sensible:

```
[[ "$(networksetup -getnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1')" = "Enabled" ]] \
&& networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1' off \
|| networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1' on
```