# Auto schedule Ethernet to activate/inactivate

Tags: network, automator, ethernet

I use a USB-C Ethernet dongle on my MacBook Pro. I frequently find it has stopped working and suspect it's due to the dongle overheating.

I'd like to automate this sequence:

- Inactivate Ethernet at 1am (after I go to bed).
- Activate Ethernet at 7am (before I start working).

Is that possible by Automator or by a 3rd party app?

Comment: You could get better help if you also described what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [automator ethernet toggle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341534/automator-ethernet-toggle-high-sierra)?

> ```
> do shell script "networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled \"Ethernet 1\" off"
> ```
>
> ...
> But, since your entire AppleScript is, in fact, a shell command wrapped inside a do shell script command, then I'd recommend using an Execute Shell Script action in your Automator workflow instead of an AppleScript one. Then you can simply write the command out in its naked form, which is much more sensible:
>
> ```
> [[ "$(networksetup -getnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1')" = "Enabled" ]] \
> && networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1' off \
> || networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled 'Ethernet 1' on
> ```

If this works, the AppleScript, Automator workflow, or shell script [can be scheduled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317118/open-an-application-periodically-in-mac-osx?noredirect=1&lq=1) using Calendar, `launchd` or a tool like [Power Manager](https://dssw.co.uk/powermanager).

Comment: If the system is sleeping will **Power Manager** wake the system for the event to occur?

Comment: Yes, Power Manager can wake a sleeping computer to a schedule – or even power it on, if desired. In this situation, I would add a call to `caffeinate` to ensure macOS does not force the computer back to sleep too quickly.